# I have an error in Clojure and leiningen command

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am working on a project in Clojure. I tried to migrate my latest DB commit to my local using the command

`PROFILE=dev lein ragtime migrate`

Getting this error:

> clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: Syntax error macroexpanding
> clojure.core/fn at (clojure/core/unify.clj:83:18).
>
> :clojure.error{:phase :macro-syntax-check, :line 83, :column 18,
> :source "clojure/core/unify.clj", :symbol clojure.core/fn}

Comment: What versions of Clojure and ragtime are you using?

Answer (score 20):

I also encountered this issue with Leiningen 2.9.1. In my case it turned out to occur due to the `lein-ring` plugin which depends on an outdated `unify` version. The issue is already fixed in the newest `lein-ring` version though: https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring/issues/203. So upgrading `lein-ring` to `0.12.5` fixed it for me.

Comment: I can confirm that upgrading to 0.12.5 fixes the problem for me too.

Comment: I had this with Leiningen 2.9.1 and lein-uberwar "0.2.0" (which apparently was extracted from lein-ring). 0.2.1 had this fixed.

Comment: Leiningen 2.9.6 on Java 1.8.0_222 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM - lein-ring 0.12.5 fixes the issue for me as well

Answer (score 9):

I'm not 100% sure what this issue is, but it seems to be related to leiningen 2.9.x.

At first, I ran leiningen v 2.8.x (don't remember which version exactly). Then everything worked fine.

Then I updated leiningen to 2.9.1, and I got this error the next time I tried to build with leiningen.

We then updated `ring` from version 1.4.0 to 1.7.1, and the error disappeared.

Alternatively, if you have to use an old version of a library, the only fix seems to be to downgrade to leiningen 2.8:

```
lein upgrade 2.8.3
```

Comment: You're right, works perfect here event for autoexpect which is the same scenario

Comment: In my case it was the `lein-ring` plugin instead. Updated to latest version, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to 2.7.1 and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your `project.clj` is malformed. I wonder where the `ragtime` command comes from? It seems that the previous developer implemented their own plugin for ragtime integration because it differs from the way suggested in the [official wiki](https://github.com/weavejester/ragtime/wiki/Leiningen-Integration). It would be nice if you share some bits of your `project.clj` as well as the code that provides the connection b/w ragtime and lein.